# Update a spreadsheet based on dates in a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets - one that people record their own individual leave in and the second where all dates for leave are recorded across the team. I want to know if someone puts a date in their own sheet, can I get it to automatically fill this data in to the main sheet?

The individual sheet works out the number of days between two dates then keeps a running total (using networkdays formula and not taking into account bank holidays)

The main workbook has a front tab which calculates the overall number of days taken and a running total of leave left.

I want to put a date into the individual one and update the main workbook - is this even possible?

Comment: yes, but are we suppose to guess how your workbooks and worksheet data looks like ? structure ? what data goes to which row and column ? Also, SO is not a free coding service website, please upload your code attempt, and we will gladly assist you in resolving bugs or requests you have

Comment: Sorry, I often come here for help when I'm coding, this is the first time i have asked a question, so wasn't really sure of the protocol.